# ShortCut key does not appear with an action of actionmanager in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tactionmanager

I try to use actionmanager in delphi7, it is almost OK, unless I need to make the caption of the action1 to be included with the shortcut key, for example:

```
Action1 CTRL+D
```

what i need exactly when I assign to the action item a shortcut, I want it appear automatically within the button in the toolbar.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want the *caption* of the button to include information about the shortcut, e.g. "Open (Ctrl+O)"?

Comment: Shortcut keys won't be shown automatically on a button. You'd need to make that happen. Shortcuts will be shown on menus and button hints. You absolutely do **not** want to display them on toolbar buttons.

Comment: What I mean is shown in this picture, the actionmanager button's caption include the shortcut (in small font at upper).